# How can I prevent inner SELECT from returning NULL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, null

How can I prevent inner SELECT from returning NULL (when matches no rows) and force query to fail.

```
INSERT INTO tt (t1_id, t2_id) VALUES (
  (SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE ...),
  (SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE ...)
);
```

Side question: is there better way form this query (t1_id, t2_id are foreign keys, but might be NULL) ?

Comment: The best way to force the query to fail if either value is NULL is by using an `ALTER TABLE` statement to change the two columns to not allow `NULL` values.

Comment: You can still end up with NULLs in tt if one of the inner SELECTs returns no rows...

Comment: @SimonJ: There's nothing posted to support that other columns exist in the `tt` table.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tt MODIFY t1_id INTEGER NOT NULL`

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood (thought you meant t1.id and t2.id) - adding the constraint on t1_id (and t2_id) should do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like:

```
INSERT INTO tt (t1_id, t2_id)
SELECT t1.id, t2.id FROM t1, t2 WHERE ...
```

Just make sure the `SELECT` returns exactly what you want to `INSERT` - so if it's possible for `t1.id` and `t2.id` to be NULL then include the relevant clause in your `WHERE` condition (`... AND t1.id IS NOT NULL AND t2.id IS NOT NULL ...`).

You may also prefer to use `SELECT DISTINCT` if there's a chance of duplicate rows appearing.

**Edit:** If you need 2 IDs from different rows of the *same* table:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id FROM some_table AS t1, some_table AS t2
WHERE ...
```

Comment: That's certainly an improvement. but what about NULL problem? I don't want to insert the NULL.

Comment: @Łukasz Lew: If one of where conditions returns no rows, the whole query returns no rows and there are no rows inserted.

Comment: Updated, thanks. Also see note about duplicate rows - I'm not sure how relevant it is as we can't see your real query :)

Comment: and what would be the syntax if t1 and t2 is the same table? (I need 2 different id's from it)

Comment: Updated for 2 IDs from different rows - I think that's what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO tt (t1_id, t2_id) VALUES (
  (SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE ...),
  (SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE ...)
)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE ...)
AND (SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE ...)
```

It may seem awkward and redundant but any SQL executor worth its salt won't execute each part twice.

Alternatively if t1 and t2 are related somehow:

```
INSERT INTO tt (t1_id, t2_id)
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON ...
WHERE ...
```

Comment: No, any decent SQL executor will NOT execute the SELECTs twice.

Comment: They don't have to be related. SimonJ gave valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This can be enhanced and used as given below**

INSERT INTO tt (t1_id, t2_id) 
select distinct t1.id,t2.id 
from t1,t2 
where t1.id=t2.id 
and t1.id is not null 
and t2 id is not null 
);